# Apache seg fault krb5int_key_delete Assertion destructors_set[keynum] == 1 failed

Tags: apache, segmentation-fault, kerberos

I use Apache 2.4.7 and ubuntu 14.04. the apache has been crashed with seg fault error early morning and it is due to logrotate script.

```
apache2: ../../../src/util/support/threads.c:383: krb5int_key_delete: Assertion `destructors_set[keynum] == 1' failed.
apache2: ../../../src/util/support/threads.c:383: krb5int_key_delete: Assertion `destructors_set[keynum] == 1' failed.
apache2: ../../../src/util/support/threads.c:383: krb5int_key_delete: Assertion `destructors_set[keynum] == 1' failed.
apache2: ../../../src/util/support/threads.c:383: krb5int_key_delete: Assertion `destructors_set[keynum] == 1' failed.
apache2: ../../../src/util/support/threads.c:383: krb5int_key_delete: Assertion `destructors_set[keynum] == 1' failed.
apache2: ../../../src/util/support/threads.c:383: krb5int_key_delete: Assertion `destructors_set[keynum] == 1' failed.
```

We are not using any krb modules for apache It seems to be libkrb5.so at fault. I have 5 libraries on machine as far as i found

```
dpkg -l | grep krb | grep ^i |awk '{print $2}'
krb5-locales
libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64
libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64
libkrb5-3:amd64
libkrb5support0:amd64
```

Any idea what could be using this library and even how to prevent this issue?

Comment: Here is a similar question, but have not yet found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54213685/apache-seg-fault-krb5int-key-delete-assertion-destructors-setkeynum-1-fail